# sqlalchemy query and map_imperatively subquery returns different results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.10

I've been running into an issue where I get different results when I query for a class mapped imperatively and when I run the query directly with sqlalchemy.

`types.py` file

```py
from dataclass import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class SectorEntity:
    path: str
    year: int
    sector: str
    entity_count: int
    sector_value: Optional[float]

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return """
SECTOR ENTITY
{self.path=}
{self.year=}
{self.sector=}
{self.entity_count=}
{self.sector_value=}
"""
```

`schema.py` file

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Metadata, Table, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime, Float, Integer, String


from .types import SectorEntity

metadata = MetaData()

entity_last_updated = Table(
    "entity_last_updated",
    metadata,
    Column("entity_guid", String(), primary_key=True),
    Column("sector", String()),
    Column("last_updated", DateTime(), nullable=False),
)

entity_unit = Table(
    "entity_unit",
    metadata,
    Column("entity_guid",
        String(),
        ForeignKey("entity_last_updated.entity_guid", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    Column("year", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("path", String(), primary_key=True),
    Column("sector_value", Float(), nullable=True),
)

sector_entity = (
    select(
        entity_unit.c.path,
        entity_unit.c.year,
        entity_unit.c.sector,
        func.count(entity_unit.c.entity_guid).label("entity_count"),
        func.sum(entity_unit.c.sector_value).label("sector_value"),
    )
    .join(entity_unit)
    .group_by(entity_unit.c.sector, entity_unit.c.path, entity_unit.c.year)
)

def start_mappers() -> None:
    mapper_registry = registry()
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        SectorEntity,
        sector_entity.subquery(),
    )
```

Then when running in a query
`query.py` file

```py
from typing import List
from .types import SectorEntity
from .schema import sector_entity
from sqlalchemy import func, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

async def select_sector_entity(
    *,
    session: AsyncSession,
) -> List[SectorEntity]:
    assert session.in_transaction()

    base_query = select(SectorEntity)
    result = await session.execute(base_query)
    cursor = result.scalars()
    output = list(cursor)
    cursor = (await session.execute(sector_entity)).fetchall()
    for obj in output:
        print(str(obj))
    for obj in cursor:
        print(str(obj))
    return output
```

Then the output that this produces with mock values in the db is as follows

```bash
----------------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------------
SECTOR ENTITY
    self.path='Gary'
    self.year=2016
    self.sector='709492'
    self.entity_count=2
    self.sector_value=4.5
    self.total_amount_undrawn=14365627661.01394


SECTOR ENTITY
    self.path='Gary'
    self.year=2016
    self.sector='709492'
    self.entity_count=2
    self.sector_value=4.5

('Gary', 2016, '709492', 2, 4.5)
('Gary', 2016, '935252', 1, 1.3)
```

So the query executes as a `query`, not as a mapped `subquery` does give correct and expected results from the db... but the `map_imperatively` to a type one, does not.

Any idea why that could be happening? I've been banging my head against the wall for the past two days why is that happening...

I tried also printing the query that's produced from `base_query` with `print(base_query)` and execute that against my local db, it also gives the correct result as querying without `subquery`...

`python 3.10`

Comment: I found the root issue, no solution yet. When using map_imperatively, the underlying loader from orm is trying to be using memoized data. It identifies the data by the identitykey which consists of class_name and primary_keys from the row… `path` and `year` are both primary_keys in given rows, but `sector` isn’t.  So when we process first row, the row gets added to the inner map of session_identity_map with the key. When we process the next row, session_identity_map already contains “our row” because it only uses primary_keys to identify what to look for there